# I want to run a scala file and expect the output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a `test.scala` file and save below commands in it. Then run it through scala to get output

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.json("file/path/")
df.registerTempTable("df_temptable")
df.count
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df_temptable ").collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Why can't you run it through scala?

Comment: I am able to run one by one manually,but i want to automate the process by saving all command in a file and run

Answer (score 0):

Scala code could be run as scripts, please refer the below link.
However, here Spark is a dependency to the script, adding dependency to the scala compiler would be little complex, instead use pyspark.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-scala-shell-scripts-scripting-language-examples